# java.lang.NullPointerException while adding node to the root node

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

I am trying to add a tag and it's value dynamically into the xml file through the following function.I am trying to add the tag named *first-name* and it value under the root tag. But while running the following snippet I am getting exceptions.

```
    public void write(String name) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();            
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element blobKey_E = document.createElement("first-name");
        blobKey_E.appendChild( document.createTextNode( name ) );
        // The following line produces an exception
        // LINE 27 
        document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(blobKey_E); // append the new tag under the root

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Personal Site_Testers/web/xml/xml_1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);            
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*exceptions :*

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Beans.XmlBuilder.write(XmlBuilder.java:27)
at Servlets.tester.doGet(tester.java:26)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have highlighted line number 27 in the function above.

Comment: So, which line of your code is line 27? Have you put this in a debugger and looked around?

Comment: The null pointer exception seems to indicate that either `document` or `document.getDocumentElement()` are null.

Comment: Since you never create a document element, this is none too surprising. The document element is not the root element; it's the named top element, and you need to create it and add it to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getDocumentElement()` in this case returns `null`

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getDocumentElement%28%29) for `getDocumentElement()` says the following about is functionality:

```
This is a convenience attribute that allows direct access to the child node that is the root element of the document.
```

In your case, there is no `root` `element` attached to your DOM. You may want to do a `document.appendChild(blobKey_E);` to attach `blobKey_E` to the DOM as the root element.

Ideally when you're trying to build up an XML DOM, here're the basic steps that you would need to follow:

Create Document 
Create the root element and add it to the Document
Create child elements and attach it to the root or another existing child node

```
public void write(String name) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();            
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element blobKey_E = document.createElement("first-name");
        blobKey_E.appendChild( document.createTextNode( name ) );

        /*
         * Here blobKey_E is treated as the root element for the document that you've created
         */
        document.appendChild(blobKey_E); 
//            // LINE 27 
//            document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(blobKey_E); // append the new tag under the root

        /*
         * Post this point, if you do a document.getDocumentElement(), it will no longer return 
         * a nullpointerexception because blobKey_E will be treated as the root element.
         */

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Personal Site_Testers/web/xml/xml_1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);            
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Y.E.P: errm, your code never shows where you're creating your root node and attaching to the `document` that you've created. Where is that part?

Comment: I want all that to come under a root element already there in the xml document

Comment: @Y.E.P: Unless you tell me which one you would want to treat as your `root` `element`, I can't help you much!

Comment: There is a root element already written in the xml file. I want the tag _first-name_ to go under it

Answer (score 1):

The document element is the root element, which you need to set. Change line 27 to

```
document.appendChild(blobKey_E);
```